# Possible dimension of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, lagrange-interpolation

Let $A=\{0,1,2,3\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}[X]$ be the set of all polynomials in one variable over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $V$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of functions $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a polynomial $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ with $f(a)=P(a)$ for all $a \in A$. Determine the dimension of the $\mathrm{R}$-vector space $V$.
(a) 2
(b) 3.
(c) 4.
(d) $\infty$.

I tried solving this problem by seeing that there always exists a Lagrange polynomial of degree 3 that will do our job for the part that $f(a)=P(a)$.
And since the $\mathbb{R}$ vector space V consists of all the arbitrary functions, the dimension should be infinite.

Comment: The dimension of 4-tuples of real numbers as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ is not infinite.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your reasoning.... Can you elaborate it a please...

Comment: What is the structure of $\{f: f: A \rightarrow \Bbb{R}\}$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$?  Its dimension is the size of a basis, not the a count of the number of elements.  So find a basis.

Comment: Also..... One more question why was the information about the equality of the values between $f(a)$ and $P(a)$ is given.... Is it to make the question more daunting...?

Comment: To confuse you.  The dimension of $\Bbb{R}[X]$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ is infinite - with basis e.g. $\{X^n: n\ge 0\}$.

Comment: Thanks @JohnDoe